# /bin/cat :Bad file descriptor

Tags: c

I am pretty new to the pipe(), fork() functions and /bin. I would like to pass a value through a pipe from my first child to my second child that I will later use to change the value. However, I thought that if I make `line` and just `line++` in the second child, it would be okay. However, `line` would then become a shared value. So I used `/bin/cat` to properly call out the stdout but I can't seem to get it to work.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<unistd.h>
#include<sys/types.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<sys/wait.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<unistd.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#define READ_END 0
#define WRITE_END 1
 
int fd1[2];
char line[100];
int main() 
{ 
    int line = 1;
    char *args[] = {"/bin/cat",NULL};
    //child 1 process 
    if(fork() == 0)
    {   
        close(fd1[READ_END]);
        dup2(fd1[WRITE_END], WRITE_END);
        printf("Num 1: %d\n", line);
        close(fd1[WRITE_END]);
        exit(0); 
    }
    // child 2 process 
    if (fork() == 0)
    {
        close(fd1[WRITE_END]); 
        line++;
        dup2(fd1[READ_END], READ_END);
        printf("Num 2: %d\n", line);
        close(fd1[READ_END]);
        execv("/bin/cat",args);
        exit(0);

    } 
    else if(fork() != 0);
    // Write input string and close writing end of first pipe.
    close(fd1[READ_END]);
    close(fd1[WRITE_END]);
    exit(0); 
    return 0;
}
```

My output is:

```
Num 1: 1
Num 2: 2
/bin/cat: -: Bad file descriptor
/bin/cat: closing standard input: Bad file descriptor
```

Comment: The child processes do not share the file descriptors between them. File descriptors are shared between parent-child processes. So there is no direct way to talk with other child. Maybe, write the value to the parent process, then parent process can write this value to the other child process through read() / write() system calls. Or you may use shared memory between two child processes, since they are independent.

Comment: Have you already looked at the pipe manpage (man 2 pipe or online at https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/pipe.2.html ). The manpage contains an example of an actual pipe() call followed by a fork and some communication between parent and child.

Comment: I have seen that page before. It was just that I only wanted to pass a value into my first child and use a pipe to pass it to the second child and changing it after.